# Given $f(x) = x^2 +3$. If $-2 \lt x \lt 3$ then is ... ( cf. Body)

Tags: inequality

A) $3 \le f(x) \lt 12$

B) $3 \lt f(x) \lt 12$

C) $-1 \lt f(x) \lt  12 $

D) $7 \lt f(x) \lt 12$

E) $7 \le f(x) \lt 12$

I've plugged the values $- 2$ and $3$ into the equation and it gave me answer D but the answer is A. I don't know why. Can somebody explain it for me?

By VWO OLYMPIADE question 16

Comment: What is $f(0)$?

Comment: Have you noted that $f(x)\geq f(0)=3$?

Comment: You know you can wrap entire expressions in dollar signs, not just single symbols, right?  `$3\le f(x)\lt 12$` (or even just `<` rather than `\lt`) becomes $3\le f(x)\lt 12$. Much prettier, and easier to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is A because the end points of the domain don't necessarily correspond to the end points of the range. Consider $f(0)$ compared to $f(-2)$ or $f(3)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Sir.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can draw the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Note that the extreme points of a function occur at either border points or critical (turning) points. You checked the border points $A$ and $B$. The function is maximum at the point $B$. You should also check the turning point $C$, where the function reaches its minimum. Hence, the range is between the minimum and maximum. The answer is choice $A$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Determine first the image of the interval $(-2,3)$. Observe that $f$ is an even function, increasing on $\mathbf R^+$, so that
$$f((-2,3))\subset f((-3,3))=f((0,3))=\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple "interval analysis" evaluation approach:

For $X = [-2, 3]$, we have $f(X) = [-2, 3]^2 + 3 = [0, 9] + 3$ (since $x \mapsto x^2$ maps to nonnegative numbers).